# React not re-rendering after axios post request to database

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, request, render

This app is a textbox where the user will add a text then hit post the text will be send to my express server to be stored in a database and the homepage should be auto-updated to show the newly added post but when i hit post nothing happen and i need to refresh the page manually to show the new post.

My Poster component code:

```
    import React,{useState, useRef} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import qs from "qs";


function Poster(){
    const [topic, topicSetter] = useState("");
    

    const refTopic = useRef(null);
    const url = "http://localhost:3001/";
    function update(ev){
        const va = ev.target.value;
        topicSetter(va)        
    }
   
    function Submit(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        const toPostTopic = {"idea":refTopic.current.value};
        axios.post(url, qs.stringify(toPostTopic))
        .then((res)=>{
            console.log(res.data); 
            console.log("res from axios");
        })
              

        topicSetter("");
        
    }

    return(
        <form onSubmit={(e)=>Submit(e)}>
            <textarea 
            placeholder="Tell us your perfect idea..." onChange={update} type="text" ref={refTopic}
            cols="50" rows="2" maxLength="100" className="table table-boarded poster-form"
            name="ideaPosted" value={topic}></textarea>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block poster-form-btn">Post</button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Poster;
```

My ViewerList component code:

```
import React,{useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Viewer from "./Viewer"
import axios from "axios";

const url = "http://localhost:3001/";


function ViewerList(){
   
    const [myData, setmyData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        
        axios.get(url)
        .then(res=>{
            // console.log(res.data);
            setmyData(res.data);
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));   
        
    },[])

   return <div> {myData.map((ide)=> <Viewer key={ide.key} idea={ide.idea}/>)} </div>
}

export default ViewerList;
```

Comment: It doesnt work this way. You need to either use Redux to detect change in state that would have post as an object or use socket.io to broadcast new post to all users

Comment: Which component are you trying to get to rerender? `ViewerList` only fetches and sets state when it mounts and `Poster` doesn't update any state to trigger a rerender other than to clear state/input. Perhaps in `Poster` you can pass the textarea value back to a parent component upon POST success. We need more detail/context to likely provide more help.

Comment: I'm not sure how Poster and ViewerList components are bonded (both are children of a component?) but maybe you should pass the response from 'Submit' function to the parent then pass down to the ViewerList. (If you are not using any other state managements)